# How to split query string into multiple or-related queries automatically in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a search query with Elasticsearch 2.3.3, which is able to match also compound words.
Therefore I added a [trigram-tokenizer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21000#issuecomment-274422932).
Here is a sample index:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
          ,"filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "symbol",
            "punctuation"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
},
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "trigrams" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

POST /my_index/my_type/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "text": "Aussprachewörterbuch" }
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "text": "Militärgeschichte" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "text": "Weißkopfseeadler" }
{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{ "text": "Weltgesundheitsorganisation" }
{ "index": { "_id": 5 }}
{ "text": "Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz" }
```

When you search it for `gesundheit`, it matches `Weltgesundheitsorganisation` as expected. I would like to have it a little bit more userfriendly however and have a or relation between multiple search terms.

I want the following behaviour: searching for `gesund adler` matches `Weltgesundheitsorganisation` and `Weißkopfseeadler`.

This is achieved by the second query below, but not by the first one. **Is there a more elegant way, than splitting the query manually into multiple should clauses?**

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
                "query":                "gesund adler",
                "minimum_should_match": "80%"
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "gesund",
              "minimum_should_match": "80%"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "adler",
              "minimum_should_match": "80%"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```